# Get a percentage in a pivot mysql query

Tags: mysql, aggregate, common-table-expression, mysql-8.0

My data looks like

```
 EmployeeId      paycategory            value

      1             Contribution         200
      1              Salary              18000
```

I use the following query,

```
select employeeid,
    max(case when paycategory = 'Salary'       then value end) salary,
    max(case when paycategory = 'Contribution' then value end) contribution
from reports
group by employeeid
```

The above shows the results as,

```
EmployeeId        Salary      Contribution
      1             18000           200
```

which is great. Now I want to show the percentage of contribution to salary

So I expect something like,

```
EmployeeId        Salary      Contribution      Contribution Percentage
      1             18000           200            1.11 -- (200/18000)*100
```

How do I go about it using a pivot query if possible ?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery for it like below:

```sql
select 
employeeid, 
salary, 
contribution, 
(contribution/salary)*100 Contribution_Percentage 
from (
select employeeid,
    max(case when paycategory = 'Salary'       then value end) salary,
    max(case when paycategory = 'Contribution' then value end) contribution
from reports
group by employeeid 
) t
```

[DEMO on Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1d2c47d521e66b40e10f3cb3ff063b1c)

For MySql 8.0 you can use `Common Table Expression` like below:

```sql
with cte as (
select employeeid,
    max(case when paycategory = 'Salary'       then value end) salary,
    max(case when paycategory = 'Contribution' then value end) contribution
from reports
group by employeeid 
)
select 
employeeid, 
salary, 
contribution, (contribution/salary)*100 Contribution_Percentage
from cte
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7e042a5394608dc98f5fe3e7c92f1cd)

Comment: You can use it or you can write it without `as`. Please check the fiddle